Flutter: Maintaining Relative Position of Positioned Widgets on a Responsive Image Across Different Aspect Ratios
Initial situation & expected behavior
I am placing icons on top of an image and they are supposed to be in the same relative position to the image no matter the device, screen size, ... It is crucial that the icons are always in the same relative position to the image. The coordinates of the Positioned widgets are calculated based of normalized coordinates between 0 and 100. They are then supposed to be adjusted to the available space in the LayoutBuilder such that they remain in the same relative position no matter the size of the InteractiveViewer.
Situation
My solution is working as long as the AspectRatio does not change. The icons appear in the same position no matter whether I check on my phone or the emulator.
Problem
I want to make the app as responsive as possible. Thus, I want to use an AspectRatio that fits the current device for better user experience. However, as soon as I change the AspectRatio, the icons move relatively in a vertical direction.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
  displayRatio = 9 / 14;

  return Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: displayRatio,
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) {
              double layoutWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
              double layoutHeight = constraints.maxHeight;
              return InteractiveViewer(
                onInteractionEnd: (interactionDetails) => setState(() {}),
                minScale: 1,
                maxScale: 5,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    SvgPicture.asset('assets/image.svg', fit: BoxFit.contain),
                    ...generatePositionedElements(Size(layoutWidth, layoutHeight))
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}

This is how I am creating the Positioned widgets:
Widget buildCustomWidget({
  required String identifierA,
  required String identifierB,
  required List<dynamic> items,
  required Offset coordinates,
  double? offsetA,
  double? offsetB,
  required Size size,
  required double itemSize,
  required VoidCallback onTapAction,
}) {
  double xPos = offsetA != null ? ((coordinates.dx * size.width) / 100) + offsetA : (coordinates.dx / 100) * size.width;
  double yPos = offsetB != null ? ((coordinates.dy * size.height) / 100) + offsetB : (coordinates.dy / 100) * size.height;

  return Positioned(
    left: xPos,
    top: yPos,
    child: FractionalTranslation(
      translation: const Offset(-0.5, -0.5),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: onTapAction,
        child: Container(
          width: itemSize,
          height: itemSize,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

I would be very grateful for any input! Thank you in advance!
All the best!

do you know the size of assets/image.svg?

I do, I will put the file in the assets so it will be the same for every user. Does that help?

I see you already found the issue so...

Well yes, but it was really more a trial and error solution rather than something I came up by thinking about it logically. So if you have any insights into understanding the issue in more depth I'd still be super grateful!

By removing the AspectRatio widget and allowing for differing ratios across devices, the icons were offset as mentioned in the intial question. It was, thus, clear that there was a need to correct for the different ratios.
By simply multiplying the resulting y coordinate with the AspectRatio of the given LayoutBuilder, the icons are displayed at the same relative position across devices.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
  return Flex(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        aspectRatio: displayRatio,
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            return InteractiveViewer(
              onInteractionEnd: (interactionDetails) => setState(() {}),
              minScale: 1,
              maxScale: 5,
              child: Center(
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset('assets/image.png', fit: BoxFit.contain),
                    ...generatePositionedElements(constraints.biggest)
                  ],
                )
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}

With landscape mode one might have to look closer at the x coordinates as well.
